# Is it even possible to use Express Checkout for recurring payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions, express-checkout

We all know documentations can be poorly writting sometimes, but Paypal's documentation really is on another level. I've been trying to wrap my head around the Express Checkout server side rest API, to no avail.

A couple of questions:

1. Is it even possible to use Express Checkout for recurring payments?
2. If yes, where do I get the paymentID for the agreement.
3. If I use the rest API with Express Checkout, do I have to be PCI pci compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible.  PayPal's documentation is great, but it's just a matter of knowing exactly what you need.  They have so many products and options for integrating their services that it can be a bit overwhelming.

Here is a [quick reference for all the REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/directory/#paypal-rest-solutions-and-apis).  For recurring payments you'll want to study the Billing Agreements and Billing Plans sections.

Another option which would make things very quick and easy is to take a look at our [PayPal PHP class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It has functional samples and empty templates for all the Express Checkout calls.

Comment: Thanks for the links, it cleared a couple of things for me. Just a couple of questions though. If I use the server-side rest API, I have to process the creditcard payments through my server, instead of it going to the paypal express checkout window popup thing, correct?